# Creation of thread with an dynamic argument

Tags: c++

I am creating a thread from main thread with an dynamic allocated object as an argument. But if we are deleting this dynamic memory allocated object in main thread then how can we find out a object is deleted in created thread.
main thread  code :

```
int CLocalReader::Run()
{
TReaderArgument *readerArg = new TReaderArgument;
readerArg->iFinished = &theFinishedACE;
readerArg->iSelf = this;

#ifdef WIN32
if (ACE_Thread::spawn((ACE_THR_FUNC)LocalReaderFunc, readerArg) == -1) 
{
ACE_DEBUG((LM_DEBUG,"Could not start reader\n")); 
delete readerArg;
readerArg = NULL;
}
#else
if (ACE_Thread_Manager::instance()->spawn(ACE_THR_FUNC (LocalReaderFunc), readerArg, THR_NEW_LWP | THR_DETACHED) < 0) 
{
ACE_DEBUG((LM_DEBUG,"Could not start reader\n")); 
delete readerArg;
readerArg = NULL;
}
#endif
return KErrNone;
```

}

```
static void *ReaderFunc(void *arg)
{
ASSERT(arg);
ACE_Thread::yield();
ACE_OS::sleep(ACE_Time_Value(0, STARTUP_TIME));

TReaderArgument *rarg = (TReaderArgument *)arg;

CLocalReader *self = static_cast<CLocalReader *>(rarg->iSelf);
int *finished = rarg->iFinished;
while (!(*finished))
{
if( self->GetData() != KErrorNone )
{
ACE_DEBUG((LM_DEBUG, "%D LocalReader : Error receiving data\n"));
}
}
return 0;
}
```

if in above code , this object is deleted then how we can check in thread function self object is deleted

Comment: Update the code you provided. `if` statements are only valid in function sections as far as I can tell. It's not really clear which part of your code is where... `Arg` is a class instance or is `Arg->iSelf` a static instance? I also don't see any fact that any object is being deleted here. Since the object is probably in the heap. Even if you loose reference to the object. It will be still pretty much alive unless you delete it explicitely.

Comment: In main thread we have to delete the object this object explicitely in one condition. But I am not getting how to check in thread function that this object is deleted.

Comment: (1) Indent your code. (2) Suppose you find out the object was deleted, what are you going to do with this knowledge?

Comment: When the CLocalReader object is deleted in main thread but this address (self) is still use in creating thread. Can there is way we can terminate the thread also when we delete the object or notify to thread that the object(self) is deleted and come out of the loop. Can someone please suggest me the solution? thanks for help in advance.

Comment: Is it possible to make sure the object is not deleted until the thread has joined the main thread?

Comment: If it's an error to delete that object before the thread has a chance to look at it, then don't delete it. If it's not an error, then the thread doesn't need it anyway and should not touch it.

Comment: OTOH if you have to *notify* the thread about the object being deleted, you need to set up a proper synchronization and notification mechanism. The object has to be protected by a mutex. A shared boolean variable, protected by the same mutex, would then indicate whether the object is alive or not.

Comment: @ juanchopanza.. It's not possible like this. It's a configuration object when new configuration is loaded we have to delete the old configuration object and new configuration object will be created with new configuration.

Comment: OK, then it sounds like you need some notification mechanism to notify the worker thread when this happens.

Comment: @n.m..thanks for you suggestion. I will try to do this approach.

Comment: @n.m/ juanchopanza ..can you please provide some link or example code to  provide the notification mechanism to thread?

Answer (score 0):

Use reference counting like in COM. When the main thread is done with the object, it can set a flag "deleted" and release the object. The object will not be deleted yet, because the thread is still holding the reference count. But, the thread can check the flag and release the object if the flag is set. The reference count will drop to 0 and the object will commit suicide by calling `delete this;`